# Can I deploy company-only app in play store?

Tags: android, google-play

We are planning an app for Android, that can be used by our employees only. When opened for the first time, the app asks the user for the user's company-login and uses it for authentication then.

Is there any policy by Google that prohibits publishing this kind of app in the public Play Store?

Due to our structure, it is not possible to use MDM for deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any policy by Google that prohibits publishing this kind of app in the public Play Store?

No.